# Salicylic acid - polarity and solubility

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, polarity

Really confused about this, since there is carbon and two other types of atoms: should be polar, right? However, some people online say it is non-polar. Also, is it soluble in water?

Comment: I'm going to bed, but some hints, before I come back to answer (if no one else does): You should think of the shape, as well as the atoms themselves. Types of atoms aren't the only important factors in predicting polarity. An example is Carbon dioxide. And if a substance is polar, it'll assumingly dissolve in water, but that's a rule of thumb.

Comment: The shape tells me it is polar: not symmetrical at all. Also, since there is carbon and hydrogen PLUS oxygen, it should be polar. However, I don't think it dissolves in water well, so maybe non-polar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it has polar groups - carboxylic and phenolic but benzene ring reduces its polarity. One could say carbon atoms win 7:3 with oxygens, but it's still not bad :) [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/salicylic_acid#section=Solubility) say it's solubility is about 2g/L, but [this site](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=1777) gives more info - it dissolves much better in hot water and its solubility in methanol, which is quite polar, is good, and in benzene (non-polar) bad. Generally it seems to be somewhere in the middle between strongly polar and strongly non-polar compounds.

Comment: So would you say it has dipole dipole forces or not?

Comment: Yes, also hydrogen bonding.